# MySQL granting privileges on wildcard database name to new user

Tags: mysql

I am trying to keep my MySQL user accounts as restricted as possible with privileges, only granting the bare minimum for what I need.

I have a user called `creator` which I want to use to create new users, create new databases, and assign those users privileges to those databases, but only to a database of a certain format.

To create the `creator` user, I have the following (run as root):

```
GRANT CREATE USER, CREATE ON *.* TO 'creator'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `my_prefix\_%`.* TO 'creator'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Now I would assume that this would give me the ability to create a new user, and assign it any privileges to a table matching my_prefix_%, but that does not seem to be the case. Running the following queries as the `creator` user gives me an error.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `my_prefix_test`;
CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

These work and I can create the user and the database just fine. Then trying to assign the privileges to the new user on the new database I get the following:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `my_prefix_test`.* TO 'test'@'localhost';

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'creator'@'localhost' to database 'my_prefix_test'
```

I also flushed privileges to be safe.

Does anyone have any insight into the issue? Would this be more easily accomplished with stored procedures? Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly enough, this does seem to work for me, although it shouldn't. Since, like you said, an underscore as a literal means a  one character wildcard. I wonder if this is a bug with MySQL possibly?

Comment: Don't know if it's a bug. The `_` are apparently working as wildcards, because I can create the database `my_prefixxtest` and grant to it accordingly.  I can't make it work by backslash-escaping both `_` though.

Comment: I was able to create a database of `myotherdb` and try to grant all privileges to the `test` user to it unsuccessfully (this is what I was going for). I think this should be good enough, thanks! I would be happy to accept your answer if you post one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the MySQL `GRANT` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html), wildcard characters `_` and `%` need to be backslash-escaped to be used as literals in the database name.  In your attempt at the top, you have escaped one `_` as `\_` but not the other.  If you do escape both underscores, you can achieve correct grants.  The trick though, is that you must *also* escape them later when issuing the `GRANT` statement as the `creator` user to the `test` user:

Login as root (or a fully privileged user):

```
-- As root:
GRANT CREATE USER, CREATE ON *.* TO 'creator'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
-- Escape both underscores here
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `my\_prefix\_%`.* TO 'creator'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Login as `creator`:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `my_prefix_test`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

-- Issue the GRANT but escape the underscores.
-- because creator@localhost does not have permission to grant on 
-- a pattern like myXprefixXtest, as the unescaped _ wildcards would allow
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `my\_prefix\_test`.* TO 'test'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Login as `test`, the grant works:

```
USE my_prefix_test;
CREATE TABLE t (id INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Michael, you are amazing. I think what I really needed was to escape the underscores in the second grant (as creator). Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: This tip permit to user create database without start with prefix such other_prefix_database